# did I find a libxml2 bug (memory leak in multi-threaded parsing)?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, openmp, libxml2

I am working actually on a data processing code using [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). I am stuck on a memory leak impossible to remove . Here is a minimal code to generate it :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void)
{
    xmlDoc *doc;
    int tn;
    char fname[32];

    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    xmlInitParser();
    #pragma omp parallel private(doc,tn,fname)
    {
        tn  = omp_get_thread_num();
        sprintf(fname,"testdoc%d.xml",tn);
        doc = xmlReadFile(fname,NULL,0);
        printf("document %s parsed on thread %d (%p)\n",fname,tn,doc);
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    }
    xmlCleanupParser();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

At runtime, output is :

```
document testdoc0.xml parsed on thread 0 (0x1005413a0)
document testdoc1.xml parsed on thread 1 (0x1005543c0)
```

confirming that we really have multi-threading and that `doc` is really private in the parallel region. One can notice that I applied correctly the thread safety instructions for using libxml2 (http://xmlsoft.org/threads.html). Valgrind reports :

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
    in use at exit: 9,000 bytes in 8 blocks
  total heap usage: 956 allocs, 948 frees, 184,464 bytes allocated

968 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 8
   at 0x1000107AF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
   by 0x1000B2590: xmlGetGlobalState (in /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib)
   by 0x1000B1A18: __xmlDefaultSAXHandler (in /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib)
   by 0x100106D18: xmlDefaultSAXHandlerInit (in /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib)
   by 0x100041BE7: xmlInitParserCtxt (in /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib)
   by 0x100042145: xmlNewParserCtxt (in /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib)
   by 0x10004615E: xmlCreateURLParserCtxt (in /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib)
   by 0x10005B56B: xmlReadFile (in /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib)
   by 0x100000E03: main.omp_fn.0 (in ./xtest)
   by 0x100028FA3: gomp_thread_start (in /opt/local/lib/gcc44/libgomp.1.dylib)
   by 0x1001E8535: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
   by 0x1001E83E8: thread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)

LEAK SUMMARY:
   definitely lost: 968 bytes in 1 blocks
   indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   still reachable: 8,032 bytes in 7 blocks
        suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
```

This is working for me whatever the XML document used. I am using libxml 2.7.8, on Mac OS X 10.6.5 with gcc 4.4.5.

Is someone able to reproduce this bug ?

Thanks,

Antonin

Comment: I don't see any what that code could generate that output.  Maybe you trimmed the code too much.

Comment: Is the size of the leak dependant on which XML file you parse?

Comment: @Hans Passant : I don't see neither why this code is doing that, but it is, in a clean environment. I want to know if other people are able to reproduce that before reporting a bug.

Comment: @AShelly : no, the badly freed memory is something from the global environment of libxml2, independent of the XML file. I think about a bug because `xmlCleanupParser` SHOULD free this block.

Comment: Not what I meant.  I don't see how the snippet could start two threads.  Ought to be relevant to whomever tries this.

Comment: @Hans Passant : I see, two threads are starting because I use a dual core CPU, this is something automatic from OpenMP. I edited my code to clarify the question.

Comment: @Antonin : did you notice your 'fname' wasn't printed in the output ?

Comment: @YeenFei : I just forgot to update the example output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably bring this up on the libxml2 mailing list.

http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/xml

Comment: I put it on the libxml2 bugzilla, I just wanted to post here something to know if someone is able to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 3):

From the web site you listed above (http://xmlsoft.org/threads.html):

> Starting with 2.4.7, libxml2 makes provisions to ensure that concurrent threads can safely work in parallel parsing **different** documents.

Your example seems to be using an xmlReadFile for the same document (testdoc.xml) for each thread.  It further states:

> Note that the thread safety cannot be ensured for multiple threads sharing the same document, the locking must be done at the application level ...

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But sadly the original code that I am working on use really different documents, I modified my example code (and edited my question) and the leak remain.